# Crash in App no error in code

Tags: android

I'm having a big issue right now. I have a proyect to send and in the last moment there's an issue with the last function. All proyect works fine except the las function roll ("dados") as most of the code is in Spanish (My mother tongue) you will see a lot of spanish but the dice class is fully in english.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B148ladEOxa1dXJkaGx6dkVtZlU/view

I don't know what to do, I tried to debug but I don't see anything wrong. Problaby I'm missing something...

Thanks a lot for your help guys
//
Here is the error:

```
06-06 10:36:46.763 8836-8836/es.dam.sergio.proyectofinal E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: es.dam.sergio.proyectofinal, PID: 8836
                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{es.dam.sergio.proyectofinal/es.dam.sergio.proyectofinal.dados}: java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10058 nor current process has android.permission.WAKE_LOCK.
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10058 nor current process has android.permission.WAKE_LOCK.
                                                                               at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1546)
                                                                               at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1499)
                                                                               at android.os.IPowerManager$Stub$Proxy.acquireWakeLock(IPowerManager.java:337)
                                                                               at android.os.PowerManager$WakeLock.acquireLocked(PowerManager.java:974)
                                                                               at android.os.PowerManager$WakeLock.acquire(PowerManager.java:942)
                                                                               at es.dam.sergio.proyectofinal.dados.onCreate(dados.java:33)
                                                                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
06-06 10:36:48.444 8836-8836/es.dam.sergio.proyectofinal I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 8836 SIG: 9
```

//

Here is the manifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/portada"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Reglas"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".reglasMain"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".reglasClanes"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".reglasExperiencia"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".map"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".barImage"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".bosqueImage"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".calleImage"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".parkingImage"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".acciones"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".dados"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".hojapj"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".atributospj"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".datospj"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".talentospj"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".tecnicaspj"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".conocimientospj"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".disciplinaspj"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".transfondopj"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".virtudespj"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".estadisticaspj"></activity>



</application>
```

Second error after adding permissions.

```
06-06 11:27:40.414 13662-13662/es.dam.sergio.proyectofinal E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: es.dam.sergio.proyectofinal, PID: 13662
                                                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{es.dam.sergio.proyectofinal/es.dam.sergio.proyectofinal.dados}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #73: Error inflating class com.flip.diceroller.DieButton
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
                                                                              Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #73: Error inflating class com.flip.diceroller.DieButton
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:757)
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:378)
                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2145)
                                                                                 at es.dam.sergio.proyectofinal.dados.onCreate(dados.java:35)
                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
                                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.flip.diceroller.DieButton" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/es.dam.sergio.proyectofinal-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                                                 at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                                 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                                                                                 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:571)
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:378) 
                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2145) 
                                                                                 at es.dam.sergio.proyectofinal.dados.onCreate(dados.java:35) 
                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 
                                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
                                                                                Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.flip.diceroller.DieButton" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/es.dam.sergio.proyectofinal/files/instant-run/dex/slice-support-annotations-23.1.1_b952757f2113b6ade13ca7c400dcf4dfb352b6bf-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/es.dam.sergio.proyectofinal/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_9-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/es.dam.sergio.proyectofinal/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_8-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/es.dam.sergio.proyectofinal/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_7-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/es.dam.sergio.proyectofinal/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_6-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/es.dam.sergio.proyectofinal/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_5-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/es.dam.sergio.proyectofinal/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_4-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/es.dam.sergio.proyectofinal/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_3-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/es.dam.sergio.proyectofinal/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_2-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/es.dam.sergio.proyectofinal/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_1-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/es.dam.sergio.proyectofinal/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_0-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/es.dam.sergio.proyectofinal/files/instant-run/dex/slice-internal_impl-23.1.1_93238ed2e7d919a6201e977bdb17c9e84f4f91f8-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/es.dam.sergio.
```

Comment: need more information to answer this question..

Comment: If it crashes, theres an exception with more information in the stacktrace. Post the stacktrace so we can help.

Comment: The issue is that when you click on "dados" instead of taking you to the activity, the app crash. 
I don't know why. Because the other Intents to move around Activitys works.

Comment: Eddited in the main post.

Comment: Post your manifest file. I think you may have missed  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />` permission in your manifest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem:

> ```
> java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10058 nor current process has android.permission.WAKE_LOCK
> ```

`uses-permission` goes under the `manifest` element, not under `application` in manifest files.

---

Second problem:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.flip.diceroller.DieButton" on path

Your layout XML file references a class that is not found in the APK. There is not enough info in the question to tell exactly why.

Comment: Do you mean like this? 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="es.dam.sergio.proyectofinal">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/portada"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
     
        </activity>



    </application>

</manifest>

Comment: Something like that, yes.

Comment: Exception seen in logcat still the same?

Comment: I think so anyway I'll post it because I've been all night working in this and probably I'm missing all things